# Draw opposite of cgpath

Tags: ios

I have a method which receives `cgPath` and then fills it with color. What I want is to invert the path so i can fill the opposite part of path. How can I do that ?

Method and what I have

```
open func drawFilledPath(context: CGContext, path: CGPath, fill: Fill, fillAlpha: CGFloat) {
    guard let viewPortHandler = self.viewPortHandler
        else { return }

    context.saveGState()
    context.beginPath()
    context.addPath(path)

    context.setAlpha(fillAlpha)

    fill.fillPath(context: context, rect: viewPortHandler.contentRect)

    context.restoreGState()
}
```